# MATLAB: Removing a character from a table (that's within a struct)

Tags: matlab, char

I have a .mat file with the name faceDatasetGroundTruth.mat (a struct) that contains a table (called 'faceDataset')  with two columns.

Each value in the second column starts and ends with a ' character, which I'd like to remove so that I'm only left with [95,71,226,313] in the first row, for example (see attached image).

How can I remove the ' symbol from the second column of the table?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The strings are shown like that in the GUI so that you c and tell it’s a string. But the string itself will not have those quotes. Try extracting an individual element from the table and see!

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I need the right column cells to be arrays instead of strings.

Comment: Then you want to `eval` each of those strings in a loop. `eval` can run any code, so be sure your strings are just representations of arrays, and don’t include any function calls and so on.